# Maven "mvn" command only Runs as Administrator, need regular users

Tags: java, windows, maven

I setup Maven properly on Windows, adding System Variable and Path Variable.
However, `mvn -v` only works, if I am logged in as Administrator in CommandLine,  (not as regular user). That means I right click on command prompt and do "Run as Administrator". How can I ensure mvn works for regular users? Java command doesn't have this issue on my computer.

[image]

[image]

Note: I can go to the actual Maven folder as regular user in command prompt C:\apache-maven-3.9.1 and get the verrsion.

[image]

Comment: And ... what about my second question?   And is that setting correct?

Comment: OK ... but the point is that the Windows shell etc will be using the shell's *effective* settings for %PATH% and %MAVEN_HOME% *for the user* to work out where the `mvn` command is.  Did you check what the environment variable settings were *in the shell*?

Comment: hi @StephenC doing "set" command in windows, shows the exact same as control panel

Comment: Is that in the shell running as the normal user?  Also ... did you try setting the %PATH% entry to "C:\apache-maven-3.9.1\bin" directly?

Comment: How did you install it? `choco install maven` doesn't require adding/changing environment variables.

Comment: If you are touching the environment variables, make sure to start a new console after you applied the changes, otherwise they won't be picked up.

Comment: It's not enough to start a new console, unless you have a [startup profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3) that reads the environment variables and sets the `%PATH%`. If you don't, then you need to sign out and sign in again.

Comment: @MavaddatJavid Feel free to try it yourself: The changed environment variables are available in new console windows the second you've clicked the "OK" button of the "Environment Variables" dialog. No need to sign off and on. Maybe that is necessary for environment variables defined via a group policy when the computer belongs to a domain, but not for environment variables defined locally using the "Environment Variables" dialog under the "System Properties"/"Advanced System Settings" dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging from your screenshots, your **System** PATH tries to substitute the environent variable MAVEN_HOME, which is only defined as a **User** environment variable. The values of the user environment variables are not available at the time the system environment variables are set, so the actual PATH will contain the unsubstituted, literal string `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`. Removing all user variables called MAVEN_HOME (for all users) and adding a system variable MAVEN_HOME with the correct path should resolve the issue.

I can't find any current official documentation of this behavior, but the Internet Archive contains an old version of [the Windows 2000 documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20120112040128/https://support.microsoft.com/kb/100843) with a short explanation of the mechanism under the heading "How environment variables are set". The `autoexec.bat` part doesn't apply to newer versions of Windows.